# Exchange 2019 To replace Exchange 2013 in Hybrid Environment

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchange-2013, exchange-hybrid, exchange-2019

After the recent Exchange Vulnerabilities were announced, we disconnected our Exchange 2013 server in our hybrid configuration and investigated any impact. There was none, but it has been decided that we should no longer use this one and replace it with a new Exchange 2019 server. Something we were planning to do anyway.

With Exchange 2019 installed on the new server, when we run the Hybrid Configuration Wizard, we get an error `HCW8045 - No TLS Certificate Name specified`. We use a multi-domain certificate for Exchange as we did on our old server. We have found 1 post on Reddit with no replies and no other mention of this error that we can find.

Anyone seen this before, know what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link about the requirements of certificate in a hybrid environment, please check if it's helpful to you: **[Certificate requirements for a hybrid deployment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/certificate-requirements#certificate-requirements-for-a-hybrid-deployment)**